# Navigation to other pages in single-page Angular app - the page title is not properly captured by timeonsite tracker JS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, analytics, angular-routing

Integrated the [timeonsite JS](https://saleemkce.github.io/timeonsite) tracker in my Angular application in HTML  tag as follows,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Tos;
(function(d, s, id, file) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.onload = function() {
        var config = {
            trackBy: 'seconds',

            blacklistUrl: ['http://nature-home.local/#contact'],
            
            developerMode: true, //optional setting
            
            callback: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                // give your endpoint URL/ server-side URL that is going to handle your TOS data which is of POST method. Eg. PHP, nodejs or python URL which saves this data to your DB
                var endPointUrl = 'http://nature-home.local/api/tos'; // replace with your endpoint URL
                if (data && data.trackingType) {
                    if (data.trackingType == 'tos') {
                        if (Tos.verifyData(data) != 'valid') {
                            console.log('Data abolished!');
                            return; 
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // makes use of sendBeacon API in your browser.
                    if (navigator && typeof navigator.sendBeacon === 'function') {
                        var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {type : 'application/json'});
                        navigator.sendBeacon(endPointUrl, blob);
                    }
                }
            }
            
        };
        if(TimeOnSiteTracker) {
            Tos = new TimeOnSiteTracker(config);
        }
    };
    js.src = file;fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
} (document, 'script', 'TimeOnSiteTracker', 'js/timeonsitetracker.js'));
```

On page reloads and refresh, I'm able to see data captured in tracking table correctly. I'm using `sendBeacon()` API to capture data in a real-time & loss-less fashion.

From ***http://nature-home.local/#home*** page, I see the record captured as:

```
{
    "TOSId": 10271953114371370,
    "TOSSessionKey": "6454165596535779179057",
    "TOSUserId": "anonymous",
    "URL": "http://nature-home.local/#home",
    "title": "Nature Posts - Home",
    "entryTime": "2022-06-23 06:22:37.787",
    "currentTime": "2022-06-23 06:22:49.489",
    "timeOnPage": 12,
    "timeOnPageTrackedBy": "second",
    "timeOnSite": 12,
    "timeOnPageByDuration": "0d 00h 00m 12s",
    "timeOnSiteByDuration": "0d 00h 00m 12s",
    "trackingType": "tos"
}
```

From ***http://nature-home.local/#product*** page, I see the record captured as:

```
{
    "TOSId": 15426974499706884,
    "TOSSessionKey": "6454165596535779179057",
    "TOSUserId": "anonymous",
    "URL": "http://nature-home.local/#home",
    "title": "Nature Posts - Home",
    "entryTime": "2022-06-23 06:24:49.449",
    "currentTime": "2022-06-23 06:24:52.497",
    "timeOnPage": 3,
    "timeOnPageTrackedBy": "second",
    "timeOnSite": 15,
    "timeOnPageByDuration": "0d 00h 00m 03s",
    "timeOnSiteByDuration": "0d 00h 00m 15s",
    "trackingType": "tos"
}
```

From ***http://nature-home.local/#photos*** page, I see the record captured as:

```
  {
    "TOSId": 4699630142561574,
    "TOSSessionKey": "6454165596535779179057",
    "TOSUserId": "anonymous",
    "URL": "http://nature-home.local/#home",
    "title": "Nature Posts - Home",
    "entryTime": "2022-06-23 06:25:18.873",
    "currentTime": "2022-06-23 06:25:29.624",
    "timeOnPage": 11,
    "timeOnPageTrackedBy": "second",
    "timeOnSite": 26,
    "timeOnPageByDuration": "0d 00h 00m 11s",
    "timeOnSiteByDuration": "0d 00h 00m 26s",
    "trackingType": "tos"
  }
```

As you see, the **URL** field is pointing to ***http://nature-home.local/#home*** - home page only in all three page navigation instead of `/products` and `/photos` pages respectively.

Is it a bug in ***timeonsitetracker.js*** library or am I missing anything here? For your information, I haven't seen this issue in web application (non single-page app). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need to call `sendBeacon()` API on Angular route change and get the actual URL from Angular router

Comment: Do you have sample code on how to do this with Angular router? I don't find any except giving URL by _request_ or _callback_ options while initializing the tracker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a bug in timeonsitetracker.js library or am I missing anything
> here? For your information, I haven't seen this issue in web
> application (non single-page app). Thanks in advance.

It's neither a bug ***timeonsite.js*** nor a misbehavior in Angular app's routing module but you are missing a very significant setting while initializing the Single-page apps. Timeonsite.js is a capture of continuous stream of timing data, real-time in web and mobile browsers; That means there is nothing that stops or restarts tracking the stay time of users. It just cuts real-time session as pageviews and time-on-page based on page refresh, reaload or browser exits. But for single-page/Angular apps, there is a strategic navigation called **"Hash-based"** routing. In this case, since the refresh or reload doesn't occur, timeonsite.js thinks that the users stays on page 1 as is. Hence this custom setting `trackHistoryChange: true,` applicable for any hash-based routing apps.

So, potentially you are missing `trackHistoryChange: true,`, a mandatory setting for single-page/Angular app. Any app that works based on hash routing should include this.

```
var config = {
    trackBy: 'seconds',

    ....
    ....
    ....

    trackHistoryChange: true, //mandatory setting for single-page app

    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

Add this missing setting and retry. It should work as expected i.e page titles and URLs would be captured on navigation properly.

[Documentation, TOS-configuration-option](https://saleemkce.github.io/timeonsite/docs/index.html#TOS-configuration-option) (Look for ***Tracking single-page apps***)

Comment: It works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It behaves this way because you are calling `sendBeacon` before the angular changes route.

I recommend you to achieve this way:

`app.component.ts`:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((routerEvent) => {
  if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    const url = routerEvent.url;
    // do the call here
  }
});
```

This `url` will be an updated one.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't fix the problem. Yes, the URL is printing in console (browser terminal) as updated ones i.e navigated paths correctly. But, the capture in timeonsite tracker is not showing updated URL in `Tos.getTimeOnPage()` API.